# Звук в Unity 5, замена audio.PlayOneShot

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь проиграть звук через audio.PlayOneShot, мне Unity подчёркивает, пишет что-то про obsolete. Максимально кратко, как проиграть MP3 один раз? Есть MP3 в Assets, есть скрипт

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class taptoscream : MonoBehaviour {
public float gts = 0;
float nosik = Scream.nos;
public AudioClip MyAudio;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(gts == nosik) { dog(); }
    if(gts > nosik) { dog(); }
}
void dog()
{
    audio.PlayOneShot(MyAudio);
}
}
```

Вот последнюю строчку подчёркивает красным. Как избежать и на что поменять? Просто проиграть звук один раз.

Comment: А вы напишите что он пишет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что пишет `obsolete`, то скорее всего ругается на `audio`.
Типа такого

> Component.audio' is obsolete: `Property audio has been deprecated. Use
>   GetComponent() instead.

В предупреждении пишут **конкретно** что делать. Вместо `audio` использовать `GetComponent<AudioSource>()`. (**Всегда читайте предупреждения и хотя бы переводите в гугл. В сообщения специально ВСЕГДА говорят, что вам делать. А не посылают на три буквы!**)

`obsolete` - это устаревший. То есть так теперь лучше не делать. Раньше можно было обратиться к компоненту по его имени, не объявляя и не инициализируя его в скрипте. Теперь надо объявлять и инициализировать. Как?

Максимально кратко:

На объекте со скриптом должен быть компонент `AudioSource`

Чтоб на нем проиграть звук один раз, надо в начале к нему обратиться (инициализировать) через `GetComponent<AudioSource>()`, как описано выше, а затем только вызвать метод `PlayOneShot`, который принимает на вход два параметра: сам звук и громкость(не обязательно). Всё! Хэппи энд.

---

Пример:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioClip impact; // наш звук
    AudioSource audio; // объявляем компонент аудио источника

    void Start() {
        // инициализируем источник издавания звуков
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        // Воспроизводим
        audio.PlayOneShot(impact, 0.7F);
    }

    /* можно использовать и так
    void OnCollisionEnter() {       
        audio.PlayOneShot(impact, 0.7F);
    }
    */
}
```

Пример взят из [официальных доков](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html)

Можно напрямую кинуть воспроизводимый файл в компонент `AudioSource` в поле `AudioClip`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вызывать метод сразу на нем:

```
AudioSource audio;  // объявляем компонент аудио источника

void Start() {
    // инициализируем источник издавания звуков
    audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();        
    // Воспроизводим        
    audio.PlayOneShot(audio.clip);
}
```

или даже так:

```
public AudioClip impact;

void Start() {
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(impact, 0.7F);
}
```

---

Т.к. вы что-то крутите в методе `Update`, который вызывается каждый фрейм, то надо следить, чтоб метод вызвался один раз, например с помощью флагов сигнализировать, типа `isPlayed` или нет. 
Иначе будет каждый фрейм обращаться к этому методу явно не один раз.